# Make Transparent Image as Footer

Tags: css

Hi everyone i was new to css, i would like to make footer simply like this:

[Footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p71SV.jpg)

So the purple is a line in menu that can merge (content in behind of footer) with its content (in yellow)..

this is what i have done but not worked

```
<style>
.footer-start {
    background-image: url('img/footer-line.png');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 31px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #a85a96;
    height: auto;
    font-family: trickpony;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    min-width: 1374px;
    margin: 0;
}
</style>
<div class="footer-start"></div>
 <div class="footer">
</div>
```

But it was look like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSh6n.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: You can use `position: absolute;` with transparent image

Comment: why did you use `display: block` in .footer-start? try removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this, Please check the code...

```css
.main-container {
position: relative;
}
.footer-start {
    background: url('https://fringetoronto.com/sites/default/files/images/kidsfest-footer-1600x350.png') bottom left;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    bottom: 0px;
    left:0px;
    min-width: 1374px;
}
.footer {
    background-color: #a85a96;
    height: 250px;
    font-family: trickpony;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    min-width: 1374px;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
<div class="footer-start"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Almost perfect, but in my html code it not merge with its footer, help :(

Comment: Cause the png image is top of my footer